# How do I select an element from JSON - Angular 2

Tags: json, angular, angular2-services

I have a big complex JSON which I have stored in a String variable. I want to get just specific elements from it. Like series_id, stadium.

I am new to angular2 so this is what is making me confused. Do I need to assign the JSON to some other variable other than String?  If yes how should I approach it?

```
  "results": {
   "Scorecard": {
    "v": "0",
    "mid": "196230",
    "m": "3",
    "series": {
     "series_id": "12624",
     "series_name": "Indian Premier League, 2017"
    },
    "ecf": "0",
    "place": {
     "vid": "90",
     "stadium": "M.Chinnaswamy Stadium, Bengaluru",
     "city": "Bengaluru",
     "country": "India",
     "Gimaget": "https://s.yimg.com/qx/cricket/fufp/images/venue_90_thumb-29-3-2011-55e03bbb85867160dc7f785dc204e8a4.jpg",
     "date": "20170416143000",
     "enddate": "20170416183000"
    }
}
```

Currently I am using the below code:

```
export class CricketComponent {
    getData: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this._cricketService.getScore()
            .subscribe(data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data));
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do with the value? For what purpose do you want to select it?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I want to put those values in a table. Just like Series : {Series_id} , Stadium: {Stadium}

Comment: What's the variable name that holds the JSON?

Comment: Here is how I am doing it curently:     getData: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this._cricketService.getScore()
            .subscribe(data => this.getData = JSON.stringify(data));
    }

Comment: What is `stringify` for? I think you should just remove that.

Comment: @parthpar the whole point of JSON is to represent a structured JavaScript object. Transforming an object to a string, when you precisely want to access the internal structure of this object, defeats the whole purpose.

Comment: @JBNizet So what would be a way around? Storing it as a list?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer removing the stringify, and storing it as an object doesn't return anything after I use you method.

Comment: @parthpar not stringifying the object. Leaving it as an object, to be able to extract the information you want out of it.

Comment: @JBNizet I did that. Removed String and just stored the JSON as object, but I am not able to display in the UI with {{getData?.results?.Scorecard?.mid}}

Comment: Then your service fails, or it doesn't return what you think it does. Use your debugger. Or add console.log() instructions to know what you actually get. Add {{ getData | json }} to your template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<td>{{getData?.results?.series_id}}</td>
```

Also remove `stringify`. Just use instead

```
getData: string; ngOnInit() { 
  this._cricketService.getScore()
  .subscribe(data => this.getData = data); 
}
```

Comment: If I am using this, it is not showing anything. My variable is getData, so I used {{getData?.results?.series_id}}

Comment: I updated my answer. When you create a string using `stringify`, you can't access individual elements anymore.